How loose are swimming styles?
I read about the controversy surrounding M Phelps victory in 2008 and his half stroke that shortened his last meters time.
This made me wonder: since there are different styles in competition, it means that there must be very precise criteria to differentiate them. Are there?
Someone competing for butterfly could swim freestyle (which I guess is faster) - so there must be something in the rules that describe the "limits" of a style?
If one looks at high jump for instance, the rule is to pass above the bar, the way you want. Fosbury did it differently and he win without controversy.
100 m sprint means you run as fast as you can, whether you do it on two legs or on all fours does not matter.
What I am trying to say is that in swimming there is both a clear goal (first to touch the wall) but how strictly is the style regulated as well?

Note that high jump is not 'the way you want'. For example, jumping off two feet is not permitted.

The World Aquatics competition regulations define backstroke (section 6), breaststroke (section 7) and butterfly (section 8); the actual definitions are far too long to quote here but as an example this is just for the arms in breaststroke:

7.3 The hands shall be pushed forward together from the breast on, under, or over the water. The elbows shall be under
water except for the final stroke before the turn, during the turn and for the final stroke at the finish. The hands
shall be brought back on or under the surface of the water. The hands shall not be brought back beyond the hip
line, except during the first stroke after the start and each turn.


Thank you - does this mean that the judges check this during a race and can disqualify someone who would not have followed the description? Or someone doing an appeal after the race stating that there were deviations from the style?

Yes. This has actually happened during the 2024 Olympic Games. According to the judges a swimmer swam too long under water without making a stroke. This gave him an unfair advantage. He was disqualified for breaking the rules.
